# Makefile for Gtk+ and cuda

Tags: user-interface, compilation, makefile, cuda, gtk

I'm trying to develop a packet analyzer with CUDA support for pattern matching. I'm using GTK+ for GUI creation but I am not able to compile the GUI file together with the cuda files. How to write makefile for this case?

The project is having two parts: 1. Analyzer 2. GUI
Analyzer consists of many .c,.h files and one .cu file.
GUI part has only one file gui.c
I have included `packet_analyzer.h` in `gui.c`.

I tried the following makefile

```
all: guitest

guitest: gui.o list.o queue.o Word.o dictionary.o packet_capturer.o rule.o aho-corasick.o aho-corasick_cuda.o packet_analyzer.o
    gcc -lpcap -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` gui.o list.o queue.o Word.o dictionary.o packet_capturer.o rule.o aho-corasick.o aho-corasick_cuda.o packet_analyzer.o

gui.o: gui.c
    gcc -lpcap -lpthread -c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` gui.c

list.o : list.c
    gcc -c list.c 

queue.o : queue.c
    gcc -c queue.c  

Word.o : Word.c Word.h
    gcc  -c Word.c  

dictionary.o : dictionary.c 
    gcc  -c dictionary.c  

rule.o : rule.c  rule.h
    gcc  -c rule.c  rule.h

packet_capturer.o : packet_capturer.c
    gcc -lpcap -lpthread -c packet_capturer.c 

aho-corasick.o : aho-corasick.c 
    gcc -lpcap -lpthread -c aho-corasick.c 

aho-corasick_cuda.o : aho-corasick_cuda.cu 
    nvcc -lpcap -lpthread -c aho-corasick_cuda.cu 

packet_analyzer.o : packet_analyzer.c  
    gcc -lpcap -lpthread -c packet_analyzer.c 

clean:
    rm -rf *o guitest
```

i end up with the following errors:

```
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `transfer_tries_from_hosttodevice(int, int, int)':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
aho-corasick_cuda.o:tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xfb): more undefined references to `cudaMalloc' follow
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `transfer_tries_from_hosttodevice(int, int, int)':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
aho-corasick_cuda.o:tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x23c): more undefined references to `cudaMemcpy' follow
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `transfer_packets_from_hosttodevice(void*)':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3b1): undefined reference to `Queue_dequeue(Queue*)'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x519): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x52b): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x53d): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x56b): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x58b): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `analyze_packets(void*)':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x663): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x683): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6dd): undefined reference to `cudaConfigureCall'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x777): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x78a): undefined reference to `Queue_dequeue(Queue*)'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7d5): undefined reference to `Queue_enqueue(Queue*, void*)'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7f3): undefined reference to `cudaFree'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x802): undefined reference to `cudaFree'
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x824): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `__device_stub__Z14AC_search_CudaPiS_S_S_S_S_S_S_PhiS_(int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, unsigned char*, int, int*)':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x85c): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x87f): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8a2): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8c5): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8e8): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
aho-corasick_cuda.o:tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x90b): more undefined references to `cudaSetupArgument' follow
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_52_tmpxft_00001608_00000000_4_aho_corasick_cuda_cpp1_ii_9958a654()':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xa82): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xae3): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFunction'
aho-corasick_cuda.o: In function `cudaError cudaLaunch<char>(char*)':
tmpxft_00001608_00000000-1_aho-corasick_cuda.cudafe1.cpp:(.text._Z10cudaLaunchIcE9cudaErrorPT_[cudaError cudaLaunch<char>(char*)]+0x14): undefined reference to `cudaLaunch'
aho-corasick_cuda.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [guitest] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you post the actual problem you are seeing?

Comment: edited the question please take a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link with the CUDA runtime library. Add `-lcudart` to your link command (and CUDA lib path if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

It's the `nvcc -lpcap -lpthread $(ANALYZER) -o packet_analyzer.o` line that's failing, right?  With the `-o` option, you're telling it to build a complete executable, not just the object files.  It needs a `main` function to do that, which I presume you don't have in any of the $(ANALYZER) files.  Instead, try compiling all the sources with the `-c` flag (like you've done with `gcc` for `gui.c`), and then wrap it all together and link it with the other `gcc` command.

Comment: thanks a lot...i changed the makefile as above but getting errors that says cuda functions are undefined...

Comment: Do you have `#include <cuda.h>` at the top of your source files that call CUDA functions?

Comment: no.without the header file(cuda.h) the analyzer part is giving output when compiled using nvcc..i tried adding the header file but getting error: cuda.h: No such file or directory.

Comment: Have you been able to compile the examples from the CUDA SDK?  That is, are you sure CUDA is correctly installed and you've been able to test other programs successfully with it?

Comment: haven't tried examples in the SDK.but i have run several other sample programs.let me try one sample from the SDK then.

Comment: tried the clock example but getting error                /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil_x86_64
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lshrutil_x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../bin/linux/release/clock] Error 1

Comment: That sounds like you haven't properly configured your dynamic linker.  If you're running GNU/Linux, create a file at `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf`, with the the two following lines inside: `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, `/usr/local/cuda/lib` (assuming you installed CUDA to the default location.  Then run `sudo ldconfig`, and try compiling the SDK samples again.

Comment: thanks now i can run the SDK samples.stil no luck with the packet analyzer.

Comment: You need to include `cuda.h` in your `.cu` file.  Besides that, I'm not sure how else I can help you without the code itself.